# Sending a Image or other data in nuSoap

Tags: web-services, nusoap

How to send a image or a file using the web service to the server ?

Comment: i have used nuSoap with text im required to send a image though the webs service ``

Comment: Am I right thinking this is in PHP? If so, the question should be tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a good example of how to send a file using NuSOAP:

http://web.imkrisna.com/june/news/simple-file-transfer-using-nusoap/

Answer (score 1):

The web service's documentation should specify the necessary format, which will probably involve base64 encoding the image data. You would do whatever encoding the web service requires and then pass it to nuSoap in the same way you already do for text.